# REGEX --ignore-files does not ignore

Tags: regex, nose

I try to ignore files matching this regular expression :

`--ignore-files="^load*\.py$"`

i want to ignore all files starting with the pattern **load**+xxx

when i do like that, the files starting with load are also listed. would please help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will only match files like

```
loa.py
load.py
loaddddd.py
```

because you forgot to add the wildcard "dot" (which means "any character"):

```
--ignore-files="^load.*\.py$"
```